# Error al tratar de imprimir "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: android-studio, imprimir

Estoy tratando de imprimir desde mi aplicación a una impresora `epson` de *red*, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mike.pos-1/base.apk", /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libepos2.so"

Alguien me puede ayudar con este error se los agradesco de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Parece que no estás apuntando a la ruta correcta del archivo `libepos2.so`. [Revisa este post](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/) que podrá ayudarte a encontrar una solución. Si no la encuentras, da más detalles en tu pregunta para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: si de echo era por que en algunas versiones de android se busca por libs/armeabi y en otras versiones por libs/armeabi-v7a ya lo pude resolver. gracias por tu apportion.

Comment: Pues me alegro. No sé si conviene que elimines la pregunta o aportar una respuesta que pudiera servir a otros usuarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione, solo se tiene que entrar a la carpeta jnLibs que te hace crear la guia de epson para poder usar sus librerias y crear la carpeta que te pida el error ya que no la encuentra y meter dentro de ella el "libepos2.so" y listo con eso funcionara de nuevo la impresion[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]